# Wordpress - prevent image files rewriting when using postname

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have Wordpress set to rewrite by **postname** in the admin permalink settings.

I use root paths for images in a gallery, eg,

```
/wp-content/themes/bones/images/portfolio/house.jpg
```

But the images are being rewritten to start with the post name, eg,

```
http://mysite.dev/design/wp-content/themes/bones/images/portfolio/house.jpg
```

... and so getting 404 responses.

How do I alter my access file to stop this happening? Here is the access file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I don't want to use the full URL for the images, that's why I want a htaccess file solution.

Answer (score 0):

Permalink settings only apply to your pages/blog etc. - not for links that you use in your posts or template.

If you use /images/portfolio/house.jpg in your post, they are certainly going to **added** to the current URL of where you are atm, e.g if you are on http://mysite.dev/design/, it's gonna be http://mysite.dev/design/wp-content/themes/bones/images/portfolio/house.jpg.

Hence in your post you could try:

```
<img src="../wp-content/themes/bones/images/portfolio/house.jpg">
```

(which is not very pretty) or use the **full URL** (which is wordpress default)

In your template use:

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/portfolio/house.jpg
```

Comment: One thing you could try though is adding a rewrite rule for images, like so: RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/bones/images/portfolio/(.*)$ http://mysite.dev/wp-content/themes/bones/images/portfolio/$1 [L] but you have to try it, just wrote that quickly.